# HTML5 - JQuery Multiple File selection for Uploads Not working if files are selected one by one

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing Multiple File Upload using HTML5 & PHP with the help of this Link https://github.com/hemantrai88/html5-php_multi-file-upload

When i Multi Select Products in one shot, all files are getting displayed in  **selectedFiles** div & when i click upload its uploading all the files.

But, When i Select a Product & clicking select files again to add 2nd file , all files are getting displayed in **selectedFiles** div & when i click upload its uploading last selected only.

I want all the products to be uploaded...

Here is the code...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="upload.css" media="screen" />
    <script>
        var selDiv = "";
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    function init() {
        document.querySelector('#upload_file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
    }

    function handleFileSelect(e) {
        if(!e.target.files) return;
        var files = e.target.files;
        for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            var f = files[i];
            selDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='file_list'>"+f.name + "</div>";
        }
                $('#uploadimages').show();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#uploadTrigger").click(function(){
        $("#upload_file").click();
            }); 
    });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="upload_pages">

           <form action="html5-php_multi-file-upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

            <input type="hidden" name="AddFiles" id="AddFiles" value="1">

            <input type="file" name="upload_file[]" class="hidden" id="upload_file" multiple />

            <hr>
            <hr>
            <strong id="form-text">Upload Images </strong>
            <div class="button" id="uploadTrigger">Select Images</div>
            <div id="selectedFiles" style="width:690px;height:400px;overflow:scroll;border:none"></div>    
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="uploadimages" />
           </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers prevent javascript from changing the files which will be uploaded: only the user can select files via the user interface. This is to prevent an evil script to upload /etc/passwd, for example, without the user knowing.

with jQuery 1.010 it's harder to do it ... but it is still possible

My solution:

To do this, you need to clone/copy/make new #upload_file element, everytime you select one or more files (and hide elements). You need to trigger click to latest #upload_file element too.

so, when I choose 3 files seperately, in document you will have:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file[]" class="hidden" id="upload_file" multiple />
<input type="file" name="upload_file[]" class="hidden" id="upload_file" multiple />
<input type="file" name="upload_file[]" class="hidden" id="upload_file" multiple />
```

each of this input contain one(or more) files, which will be uploaded